# Ansible: Generate an incremental interval, per host?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to implement an incremental interval fact for each host. I tried:

```
---
- name: Incremental interval per host
  hosts: cluster
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Set interval fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        interval: '{{ interval | default(0) | int + 10 }}'

    - name: Debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: interval
```

Expected outcome:

```
TASK [Debug] *************
ok: [apollo] => 
  period: '10'
ok: [boreas] => 
  period: '20'
ok: [cerus] => 
  period: '30'
```

Actual outcome:

```
TASK [Debug] *************
ok: [apollo] => 
  period: '10'
ok: [boreas] => 
  period: '10'
ok: [cerus] => 
  period: '10'
```

Can you please let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below task does what you want

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        period: "{{ 10 + 10 * my_idx }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: true
```

- Run the task [once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation-and-parallel-execution) and iterate [ansible_play_hosts_all](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_play_hosts_all).
- Delegate each iteration to a host and [delegate_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-facts) too to assign the fact to the delegated host.
- Use [index_var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var) to increment the period.

---

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[cluster]
apollo
boreas
cerus
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: cluster

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        period: "{{ 10 + 10 * my_idx }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_facts: true
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: period
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [cluster] *******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [apollo] => (item=apollo)
ok: [apollo -> boreas] => (item=boreas)
ok: [apollo -> cerus] => (item=cerus)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [apollo] => 
  period: '10'
ok: [boreas] => 
  period: '20'
ok: [cerus] => 
  period: '30'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
apollo: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
boreas: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
cerus: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful information, Vladimir. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible facts (and variables - which are almost, but not exactly the same thing) are belonging to a host. There is no such concept as a global variable in Ansible (except the magic, or special, variables that behave in a different way) - in the end, all the variables are flattened to the host level. That means, that your `interval` is actually unique for each host, so you're incrementing the same variable, but in distinct manner for each host of `cluster` group.

Your question doesn't contain enough information to suggest the solution, because it would depend on what you actually want to achieve.

Just a couple of examples:

- If you simply need different fixed values of the same variable for different hosts, you can set them in your inventory on host level.
- If you need a variable to depend on the host order and the difference should be fixed somehow mathemacally, you can set `interval: "{{ groups['cluster'].index(inventory_hostname) * 10 }}` on `cluster` group level. But keep  in mind that this order is not guaranteed to be the same on different executions of the playbook, or when the hosts are added/removed.
- If you need to iterate over the list of hosts and generate some values based on the discovered facts, you will need to collect them first, and then process them in a different task/play, possibly on a different host (in example, `localhost` as the control node, using `delegate_to`, `delegate_facts`, or operating `hostvars['localhost']` if you need the variable to be single).

Comment: What I’m trying to achieve is clearly stated into question, have a fact returning an int result in increments of 10, for each host. The expected outcome is presented into question, what exactly is not clear?

Comment: When you run a task on a group of hosts, by default it's running at the same time on all of the hosts of the current batch (by default 5) in parallel. Knowing that, the goal is unclear because, let's say, just having some different values for the same variable on different hosts, making them somehow dependent on some base value, and iterating over some variable on different hosts are three completely different tasks that should be solved in completely different ways.

Comment: I expanded my answer adding some examples of what I mean.